# How to set height of window from TOP position or How to change the position of window when I perform maximize operation

Tags: html, windows, extjs

**Step 1 :** I am having one window in Extjs. 
**step 2 :** The window is open with Some height and width.
**Step 3 :** I am clicking on maximize button the window is getting maximized But I      don't want that the window to cover the whole screen.On Top, I am having One Toolbar.
**Step 4 :** By maximizing the window that Toolbar is also getting overlap.

***So,Is there is way when I am maximizing the window toolbar should remain  nonoverlap***

Comment: Add a container. It should be divided into 2 separate containers, one with your top and the second one with the window.

Comment: But for example. Ext.getCmp('WindowId').setHeight('value'). will set the height of window or whether of a container.
How can I bifurcate from the Top.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by positioning it below toolbar using `position(x,y)` function and then reducing the height of the window by toolbar's height using `setHeight()` and `getHeight()` functions after maximizing the window.

```
 tools: [{
            type: 'maximize',
            handler: function (evt, toolEl, owner, tool) {
       var toolbarHeight = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('toolbar')[1].getHeight(); //getting height of the toolbar
                var window = owner.up('window');
                window.maximize( );
                window.setPosition(0, toolbarHeight);
                window.setHeight(window.getHeight()-toolbarHeight);
            }
        }]
```

[A working Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmWjOJ)